# Does the nodes of a Kubernetes cluster share memory

Tags: docker, caching, memory, kubernetes

We want to deploy an application that utilizes memory cache using docker and kubernetes with horizontal pod auto-scale, but we have no idea if the containerized application inside the pods would use the same cache since it won't be guaranteed that the pods would be in the same node when scaled by the auto-scaler.

I've tried searching for information regarding cache memory on kubernetes clusters, and all I found is a statement in a [Medium article](https://medium.com/google-cloud/kubernetes-101-pods-nodes-containers-and-clusters-c1509e409e16) that states

> the CPU and RAM resources of all nodes are effectively pooled and managed by the cluster

and a sentence in a [Mirantis blog](https://www.mirantis.com/blog/multi-container-pods-and-container-communication-in-kubernetes/)

> Containers in a Pod share the same IPC namespace, which means they can also communicate with each other using standard inter-process communications such as SystemV semaphores or POSIX shared memory.

But I can't find anything regarding pods in different nodes having access to the same cache. And these are all on 3rd party sites and not in the official kubernetes site.

I'm expecting the cache to be shared between all pods in all nodes, but I just want confirmation regarding the matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, separate pods do not generally share anything even if running on the same physical node. There are ways around this if you are very very careful and fancy but the idea is for pods to be independent anyway. Within a single pod it's easier, you can use normal shmem, but this is pretty rare since there isn't much reason to do that usually.

Comment: When building the application that uses cache, do I have to take account how kubernetes handles caching, or does kubernetes handle it and I don't have anything to worry about.

I want to know is if the application is scaled (multiple pods are generated on different nodes), the same cache is being accessed regardless of the pod being used.

Comment: "cache" is a term with a lot of different meanings. Generally in modern architectures you see network services like Memcached and Redis in place of local memory caches for the heavy lifting. You would have to be more specific about what kind cache you mean for something more specific than that.

Comment: Memory cache or RAM cache. But were abandoning the plan to rely on whether the kubernetes cluster has a distributed cache.

Comment: You definitionally can't have a distributed, shared RAM cache. As I said, that's what Memcached and Redis are used for :)